# How to differentiate between Svelte dev mode and build mode?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

The dev mode using `npm run dev`, the release mode using `npm build`

How could i know that it's currently built on dev mode or not in the code, for example:

```svelte
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte';

    onMount(function(){
        if(DEVMODE) { // --> what's the correct one?
            console.log('this is x.svelte');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure about the correct method. I share what I did on my project.

1. in `rollup.config.js`

   ```js
   import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
   const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;
   ```
2. inside `plugins:[ ]` block add this

   ```js
   replace({
       isProduction: production,
    }),
   ```

   `rollup.config.js` will look like this:

   ```js
   plugins: [
     replace({
       isProduction: production,
     }),
     svelte({
       // options
     }),
   ]
   ```
3. Then use `isProduction` inside components.

   ```js
   if (!isProduction){ console.log('Developement Mode'); }
   ```

Comment: What do i have to import in order to access "isProduction" in a svelte component? Because when i do it the way you described, i get a ReferenceError: isProduction is not defined..

Comment: `{isProduction ? "Production Mode" : "Development Mode"}` works fine for me.

Comment: IN 2022. To access `isProduction`, you should use `JSON.parse(isProduction)`.

Comment: no need to use rollup only for accessing build mode, it's a separate plugin. Just use `process.env.NODE_ENV` anywhere in the app. it should return `development` or `production` as string.

Answer (score 42):

If you are using sveltekit:

```js
import { dev } from '$app/environment';

if (dev) {
    //do in dev mode
}
```

Comment: Question is about Svelte, nor Sveltekit

Comment: Useful answer nonetheless as Sveltekit becomes increasingly popular and Google leads here.

Comment: @EricDelaCruz there is no "dev mode" in vanilla svelte, svelte is just a compiler

Comment: @KTibow What OP means is when you started your app in dev or production mode.

Comment: @EricDelaCruz there is no "start"ing of an app, as I said, Svelte is just a compiler. We could assume the poster is using Svelte with Vite, or assume they're using SvelteKit, but we have no way to tell as the commands are the same for each. And SvelteKit is much more common.

Comment: Just use `process.env.NODE_ENV` anywhere in the app. it should return `development` or `production` as string.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Svelte with Vite, you may use:

`import.meta.env.DEV` - true in **development** environment.

`import.meta.env.PROD` - true in **production** environment.

`import.meta.env.MODE` - name of the mode, if you need more control.

See Vite docs on [Env variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by checking the hostname the application is running on.
You can also use other forms like, port or even msm a localStore browser variable.

Note that I check if the application is running on the client side before using the 'window'

```
const isProduction = (): boolean => {
  // Check if is client side
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document !== undefined) {
    // check production hostname
    if (window?.location.hostname !== undefined && 
        window.location.hostname === 'YOUR_PRODUCTION_HOSTNAME') {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When using Svelte (not svelte-kit), this worked for me inside svelte components:

```
<script>
    let isProduction = import.meta.env.MODE === 'production';

    if (!isProduction) {
       console.log("Developement Mode");
    } else {
       console.log("Production Mode");
    }
</script>
```

[Thanks timdeschryver for the reference](https://github.com/timdeschryver/vite-svelte-environment-variables/blob/main/src/App.svelte)

Comment: Doesn't work (anymore)

Comment: Eric it still works for me, can you explain what are you using exactly that it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Just tried this solution and it works fine