# How to detect Development mode within Svelte code?

Tags: debugging, svelte, tailwind-css

I need to use [tailwindcss-debug-screens](https://github.com/jorenvanhee/tailwindcss-debug-screens) in Svelte application. I want the plugin component only active when Svelte application running in Development mode. How can i do it?

**Example I Imagined**

```
<body class={ devMode ? 'debug-screens' : '' }>
```

Comment: check my answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64245188/how-to-differentiate-between-svelte-dev-mode-and-build-mode/64246496#64246496